# Exclude posts by post meta value

Tags: query-posts, query, post-meta, exclude

I have constructed this query to sort posts on the home page by a set position number in a custom field. However, I need to be able to exclude posts with the position set to '0'. Below is the code working to sort the items, but I cannot get anything to work with excluding the posts.

```
<?php query_posts('meta_key=home_post_id&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC'); ?>
```

Comment: See @Maugly's answer - but you shouldn't be using [`query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$args = array(
   'meta_key'   => 'home_post_id',
   'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
   'order'      => 'DESC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key'     => 'home_post_id',
           'value'   => 0,
           'compare' => '>',
           'type'    => 'numeric',
       )
   )
);
query_posts($args);
```

Something like this should work but I haven't tested it .)
Let me know if it works..

Reference: [WP_Query - Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)